# Apache: Stealth 404 the admin area until authenticated via basic auth, then allow access

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, .htpasswd, stealth

Given a administrative area with urls like this:

```
wp-admin/
wp-admin/whatever
wp-admin/another-page
wp-adminsecretlogin
```

A standard basic-auth coverage would provide a username and password prompt on all three urls, and return a 403 on all failed auth attempts.  This is a pretty obvious signal that something exists there, and thus is an invitation to script/brute force access.

I would like to instead, require basic auth everywhere, but when not authenticated, not prompt for username and password, and instead return a 404 not found error for all urls except a `wp-adminsecretlogin/` url.  At that individual-to-the-site url, basic auth could go through, and unlock the rest of the administrative functionality (though the standard application login would still be necessary).

How would I do that via apache .htaccess or .conf directives?

Comment: ..are you sure?  Implementation on that would be incredibly hacky and fragile, for a pretty debatable/marginal security gain.

Comment: There are two advantages that I can see to not providing the basic auth password & username on every admin url:  1: brute forcing of the basic auth cannot be done until the `wp-adminsecretlogin/` url is accessed, and since that url will be a custom one for the site/blog network, that would require prior knowledge of the login url and would generally require tailoring the attack to the unique site/blog network.  2: Returning 404 will mask the standards signals to bots that a wordpress admin section is present, to discourage the frequent brute force scripting attempts that tend to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already set up something to require the authentication on all of the target URLs (both `wp-admin` and the secret URL), put this in your virtual host block:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} ^$
RewriteRule wp-admin/ - [R=404]
```

I haven't tested so I'm not entirely sure if it'll successfully short-circuit the 401 response that the authentication phase would normally send back, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

A basic auth config would respond with 401 if user/pass is incorrect. 403 (in authentication context) is reserved to **authenticated users** with no permissions to access (i.e. you have got two users on the `AuthUserFile` but also a `Require user1` and try to access with user2 with correct password)

403 is also presented when trying to list a directory directly without properly configured autoindex/directoryindex, `deny from` directives, forbiding rules by mod_rewrite or mod_security, etc. so it usually indicates not much.

Asking for basic auth on `Location /wp-adminsecretlogin` and having a RewriteRule like the one Shane provided could work ([R] only accepts 30x error codes, so it may not return a 404 correctly to the browser, but a 301), but it depends heavily on your browser and how you browse your web:

As the web server would require authentication only on a certain path, the browser could not present the basic auth header on requests that did not fire a 401 response previously, so if the very first request from your browser is to `/adminsecretlogin`, it could work (the browser assumes everything would ask for basic auth), but if you previously tried to access `/` or `/wp-admin` (no 401 response back to the browser), the browser could "think" those other contexts are public and not present the basic auth header, so the rewriterule would "deny" the access.